# MATLAB uigetfile file extension for Touchstone file

Tags: matlab

Currently have different touchstone file, .s4p, .s12p and such. Is there any general file extension for touchstone file in built-in MATLAB function uigetfile?

I tried:

```
[a,b]=uigetfile({*.SnP'});

[a,b]=uigetfile({*.sNp'}); 

[a,b]=uigetfile({*.snp'});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a wildcard in the extension:

```
[a,b]=uigetfile({'*.s*p'});
```